# Accelerometer, Orientation failded to start : Unknown error

Tags: android

I am having **Motorola Milestone xt720 (android 2.1)** in which orientation doesn't work automatically but if i enabled it and if the screen is in landscape mode then it continuously remain in landscape..so have to disable it manually to get back into normal mode.

Checking using **AndroSensor** it reports :

**Accelerometer: Failed to start :Unknown error**

Orientation : Failed to start :Unknow error

So is it a hardware problem or some application problem ?